# Is it OK to have flying leads on a differential pair?

Tags: usb, circuit-design, differential

I'm designing a small daughterboard that contains a microcontroller and a USB port. This board also has a connector to allow it to connect to a motherboard.

What I'd like to be able to do is to have a USB port on the daughterboard so that I can power it up and program it without it connected to the motherboard.

The daughterboard may also contain a USB port so the D+/D- pins are also routed out through the connector.

Is this going to be a problem, having open-ended differential "leads"?

Assume that:

- The board size total is 50mm x 50mm, the USB data traces will be no more than 5mm to the board-to-board connector or the USB connector.
- The USB connector on the daughterboard may be a more significant distance away, 100mm or more.
- The USB connector on the daugherboard has TVS diodes, I don't know if the motherboard has this or not.
- The USB on the daughterboard will not be in use at the same time as the one in the motherboard, but the connector and circuit will be there.
- Both USB ports will be full speed, USB 2.0
- The board is 4 layer with a standard stack up, signal, ground, power, signal. The daughter board USB is on the top.

So basically what I'm asking, is it OK to have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyN9gl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where X1 may not be connected on the "motherboard" side? Or if it is connected, that only J2 is used (but J1 is still present)?

I'd like to avoid, if possible, using a "USB-hub" type chip, only one USB port will ever be used at once, and there is very limited board space for what needs to go on there.

Comment: What USB speed (Full Speed, High Speed, Super Speed, ...) are you designing for?

Comment: Doesn't need to be any faster than full speed, the on-board USB is just for a boot-loader and the motherboard USB would be for a similar purpose except using a flash drive to transfer a small file (no more than 2MB and don't really care if it takes 5 minutes).

Comment: What speed will be used when using the motherboard connector? Please edit your question post to include all information needed to answer the question.

Comment: Edited, added details to the bullet points.

Comment: This is not a final answer, but at 12 Mbps you should have no problem with this. On the other hand my experience with USB is it's really easy to get a design with really hard to diagnose problems (like link dropped every few hours) due to signal integrity issues. So if you do it, keep the stubs as short as possible and route them on outer layers so you can cut them if needed.

Comment: I second that, you shouldn't have any problem with your design at Full-speed. However these bidirectional series diodes are uncommon, what are those for?

Comment: They represent tvs diodes.

Comment: 2nd paragraph mistake.

Comment: Fixed, thanks...

Comment: @RonBeyer, the TVS diodes should be connected from the lines to ground, not in series with the lines.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have it right on the actual board, it was just a quick mock-up here. I'll fix it for future generations...